# Can ArcGIS online host ESRI Map Services or OGC's WMS?

Tags: hosting, arcgis, esri, wms

Can ArcGIS Online host Web Image Layers (Web Map Services) or WMS services like ArcGIS Enterprise (on-premise)? 
The source data (e.g. FGDB or shp files) has been uploaded to AGOL under my account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Follow these steps

- You can zip your shapefile or file geodatabase.
- Sign in to your ArcGIS Online account, Go to `My Content`, Click `Add Item` and select `From my computer`.
- Click `Browse` and choose the zip file. In your case, you'll select `Map template` and continue with the sharing options to select who you want your content to be shared with.

Once set up, you can go to your item's details page and open it in map viewer to set up your map.

Comment: Thank you for your for response. My question is not about publishing a web map. Rather about publishing a map service (not Feature service) on ArcGIS Online.

Comment: As you know there are different kinds of web layers: Feature layer, Map Image Layer, tile layers, Imagery layers...... What my intention is to let ArcGIS Online host Map Image Layer or Map Service , (not Feature Layer or Feature Service).

Comment: My goal is to publish a Map Service on AGOL, similar to publishing Map services on ArcGIS Enterprise (on-premise).

Comment: The steps I shared above are going to create a hosted service whose rest endpoint can be retrieved from the layer item's details page if that's what you are looking for. A web map is nothing but a set of layers (map services or feature services) packaged in one. What is your eventual use case for the map service? If you are looking for an arcgis server manager kind of interface by agol, then that's not provided.

Comment: Thanks again. I would like to publish a map service (not the webmap) onto AGOL and share the restful endpoint/url with my clients.  My clients can refer to the url in their apps. For a map service, it would not allow clients to down load the dataset (source behind the map service).

Comment: Just FYI, on https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/layers.htm, it describes different types of web layers. The "Map Image Layer" is what I'd like to create on AGOL.